# Leetcode - AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow

Tags: address-sanitizer

Here's my code
It's my attempt to solve a leetcode problem
[https://leetcode.com/problems/majority-element-ii/](https://stackoverflow.com)
I want to know what is wrong with my code (Not in the logic part)? why is this error occurring?

```
int* majorityElement(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize){
    int *ans = (int *)malloc(2 * (sizeof(int)));
    int limit = numsSize / 3;
    int index=0;
    *returnSize = 0;

    if (limit == 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++){
            ans[index++] = nums[i];
        }
        return ans;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)
        {
            int count = 1;
            if (nums[i] != -1)
            {
                for (int j = i+1; j < numsSize; j++)
                {
                    if (nums[i] == nums[j])
                    {
                        nums[j] = -1;
                        count++;
                    }
                    if ((count > limit) && (ans[index-1] != nums[i]))
                    {
                        ans[index++] = nums[i]; 
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
    return ans;

}
```

Error

```
==22==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000002c at pc 0x556888e8ee4b bp 0x7ffdb82cf510 sp 0x7ffdb82cf500
READ of size 4 at 0x60200000002c thread T0
    #2 0x7fd2226ee082 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
0x60200000002c is located 4 bytes to the left of 8-byte region [0x602000000030,0x602000000038)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7fd2230fc887 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145
    #3 0x7fd2226ee082 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 00 04 fa[fa]00 fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==22==ABORTING
```

I read all the related topic on this error, but couldn't find what's wrong with my code. its running as expected in my native macos g++ and clang++ compiler. but not on leetcode inbuilt compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (index > 0 && count > limit && ans[index-1] != nums[i])
```

This ensures you're only accessing `ans[index-1] if index > 0`.